# Displaying a u int. I get a positive number when i subtract 1 when the value is 0

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a unsigned integer for a timer. But when I subtract 1 of it when the value is zero it displays a positive number. Like this: http://prntscr.com/2wkydb .
Here's my code Viewcontroller.m:

```
-(IBAction)btnUp:(id)sender
{
    timer = timer + 1;
    lblTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", timer];
}
-(IBAction)btnDown:(id)sender
{
    timer = timer - 1;
    lblTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", timer];
}
-(IBAction)btnRestart:(id)sender
{
    lblTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
}
```

Viewcontroller.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    unsigned int timer;
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblTimer;
}
-(IBAction)btnUp:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)btnDown:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)btnRestart:(id)sender;

@end
```

What do I need to do so it doesn't display the positive number but the timer stays on 0?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I also don't want the timer to display a negative value.

Comment: I also don't want the number to be negative.

Comment: @Bas Then check to see whether it's zero before you subtract 1 one from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsigned integers "wrap around". Subtracting 1 from zero gives (assuming 32-bit integers):

```
0xFFFFFFFF = 4294967295
```

If you don't want that then change your code to:

```
if (timer > 0)
    timer = timer - 1;
```

Even better, *disable* the "Down" button when the value reaches zero, and *enable*
it again when the value is positive.

Something like (untested, not compiler checked):

```
-(IBAction)btnUp:(UIButton *)sender
{
    timer = timer + 1;
    lblTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", timer];
    self.downButton.enabled = YES;
}
-(IBAction)btnDown:(UIButton *)sender
{
    timer = timer - 1;
    lblTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", timer];
    sender.enabled = (timer > 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, dumb that I didn't thought about that:)

Comment: When the timer reaches 0, and you press up the button down keeps disabled, how can I enable the button again? I'm new to objective -c

Comment: @Bas: There was an error in my code example, which I have fixed now. The `btnUp` method must of course enable the "down button" again.

Comment: Right now I get the error: Property 'btnDown' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'

Comment: @Bas: You have to create a "Outlet Connection" from the button to your view controller, and then use the name of that connection.

Comment: Thanks the thing I needed to change was: self.downButton.enabled = YES; to :  self->downButton.enabled = YES;

Comment: @Bas: I had written `self.downButton` because outlets are usually defined as *properties* and not as *instance variables*.

Comment: @Bas You should definitely be using `@property` declarations for your outlets.